# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, sqlclr

i am creating an C# application in which i am facing error

`"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.".`

i am getting this error while creating ADo.net entitydata model designer from database. 
I have installed "SqlSysClrType.msi" for my Sql Server 2014
and "SharedManagementObjects.msi" for my Sql Server 2014, although both were previously installed.
i am running visual studio 2013 ultimate and sql server 2014 developer edition. please help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

I can advice 2 solutions:

**Solution #1**

Use the following links:

1. http://blog.waseem-sabjee.com/2013/07/10/how-to-resolve-sqlclrprovider-not-found-without-installing-sql-server-on-the-client-machine-or-needing-a-deployment-project/
2. http://big.info/2011/12/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html

If all fails try the following solution:

**Solution #2**

On your machine where you have SQL Server installed, the *"Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll"* file is in your GAC. However, you cannot access this file without making changes to the registry.

Using the registry editor, go to *"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Fusion"*. Add a new DWORD called `DisableCacheViewer`. Give it a value of 1.

Once this change is made, you can go to *"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider\"* to get the dll you need. then add it as a reference in the project.

I hope you've found it helpful.